# I am getting an error while subtracting an number from another

Tags: javascript, discord

I tried making a `Balance Discord Bot` for my personal uses using `JSON` file to save the balance to, while trying to finish the `methods` I couldn't subtract the `number` from another, but both `types` were `typeof` a `number`.

```
if(message.content.toLowerCase() === '?setupleowhite' && message.guild.ownerID === message.author.id) {
        message.channel.send('',   {
            embed: {
                thumbnail: {
                    url: 'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/754032677275041855/754038238758305863/s-letter-logo-template_73941-2-original.jpg?width=845&height=702'
                },
                title: 'LeoWhite',
                color: '#222025',
                    description: `Hallo LeoWhite,\nIch bin ein Bot der dir helfen wird einen guten Überblick über deine gratis Coins zu behalten. In meiner Nachricht findest du deine derzeitige Bank. Um was abzuheben schreibe bitte nicht mehr unsere Owner an, sondern schreib den Command -Coinanzahl ( z.b -50 ). Das würde heißen du hebst 50 Millionen ab. Unsere Owner werden kontaktiert und dir das Geld überweisen, sei dir sicher dass du eine Bin Auktion laufen hast, die so viel kostet wie viel du angegeben hast. \n\nWenn du jedoch ein Problem findest, dass Ich dir nicht eklären kann, schreibe bitte unsere Owner an.\n\n Balance: `
            }

            
        })
               //JSON
                function jsonReader(filePath, cb) {
                    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', (err, fileData) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return cb && cb(err);
                        }
                        try {
                            const object = JSON.parse(fileData);
                            return cb && cb(null, object);
                        } catch (err) {
                            return cb && cb(err);
                        }
                    });
                }
                jsonReader('./balance.json', (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        return(data.balance)
                    }
                })
                function substractjsonBalance(balance, minus){
                    var result = balance - minus;
                    return result;
                }
                console.log(substractjsonBalance(jsonReader('./balance.json', (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(typeof data.balance);
                        console.log(data.balance)
                        return(data.balance);
                    }
                })), 5000000) 
    }
```

Comment: put log for balance inside the substractjsonBalance function. jsonReader doesnot return anything, so it should be undefined

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I would suggest reading up on promises and callbacks

Comment: This is my log: NaN 5000000
number
1000000000

Comment: It seems one of your `number` is `NaN`, could you please try to convert to `number` if possible and check the results.

Comment: To help you debug and find the solution yourself, put a console.log in `substractjsonBalance` to see what parameters it's receiving.  Then instead of having one large call, factor out the parameters your passing to subtractjsonBalance into variables and call with them.